# What is the difference between before delete and after delete?

Tags: apex, trigger

For Apex triggers, the `before` and `after` contexts for `insert` and `update` operations makes sense in that the records can be modified during `before` and not during `after`.

In the case of `delete` operations, what exactly is different between `before delete` and `after delete`? In other words, if I'm designing a trigger to run when records are deleted, what information should I take into consideration when choosing to attach the trigger to `before delete` or to `after delete`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main difference is that you can't query the deleted records, or related child records in an after delete trigger. Child records will either be deleted, or have their lookup fields set to null, depending on the field's settings.

Answer (score -1):

On the `after delete` you can block the deletion.
On the `before delete` you can perform other cascading deletes, for instance.

Comment: This answer isn't right... You can block deletes in an after trigger, and cascade deletes typically need to be done in a before trigger, otherwise you can't query the child records.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up sfdcfox, always comprehensive knowledge sharing, will amend the answer just to avoid confusion. I wonder how would be possible to block delete on after delete trigger but will need some testing on my end.

Comment: Late to the party here, but if you see this, it so happens that you can use the addError method to the Trigger.old method to prevent deletion in an after delete trigger.